# CA lisa can not establish a session with Appium for Mobile automation

Tags: android, appium, ca-lisa

I am trying to connect CA lisa to run Mobile Tests.

I have attempted to use Appium without CA Lisa and it works but when using CA 
Lisa I cannot get passed Establishing connection(should take about 30 seconds) it takes a little over an hour.

CA Lisa loads up my avd and launches the Appium Server but can not establish the session.

I am using a PC and the avd is an Android Nexus 10 but I have attempted this on many Android emulators.

If I could figure out what the Error usually means in Appium I may be able to figure out what is not working.

Every time I attempt to verify it's working I receive the following error:
Message:

> Last mobile error in log: debug: Responding to client with error:
>   {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created.
>   (Original error: Remote install failed: \tpkg:
>   /data/local/tmp/74f0c34f850ea7891cb776718411efe5.apk\r\r\nFailure
>   [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]\r\r\n)","origValue":"Remote
>   install failed: \tpkg:
>   /data/local/tmp/74f0c34f850ea7891cb776718411efe5.apk\r\r\nFailure
>   [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]\r\r\n"},"sessionId":null}

StackTrace:

> java.lang.Throwable: Unable to open Appium session, quitting after 45
>   retries   at
>   com.itko.lisa.mobile.appium.process.MobileSessionManager$Callback.doCallback(MobileSessionManager.java:275)
>     at
>   com.itko.util.swing.panels.ProcessingDialog$2.run(ProcessingDialog.java:194)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)